# Multiple ASP pages blocking each other

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis-6

I have some ASP pages calling SQL scripts.  Each ASP page takes about 20 seconds to 'run' the complete sequence of calls to the database which involves some VBScript in the ASP pages calling multiple SQL calls.

If I put the same .asp page address in two tabs of a browser, hit refresh on both pages, the second page will wait until the first page is complete before starting.  On the server itself, I can run other SQL queries without affecting the web pages or being blocked.  In fact, I can see this using another CPU core.

So, I think it is an IIS issue, not SQL

Running XP Pro 64, IIS6, ASP.NET 2, MS SQL Server 2008.

Tried various setting on IIS and playing with processes / web garden.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: try to load the same page from another browser (like opening at same time IE and Chrome for example). If this still happen then it's really as you say that IIS serializes the usage of SQL connection.

Comment: Could be a number of issues here, how are you connecting?, are you pooling connections?, are you opening/closing many connections in these two pages?  Could the SQL you are running be deadlocking?  Can you run the SQL on it's own at the same time outside of ASP?

Comment: Davide - thanks for the suggestion which perfectly answered it.  I'd tried this before.. but let me explain for others reading this:

In IE, the page takes time to load anything but the header of the page (probably need  more Flush.Response's). So IE seems to 'hang' and I was assuming this was caused by server locking

However, you can see Chrome 'working', i.e. pasting new lines as it runs. So if I run query in IE page first, quickly switch to Chrome and run it there, you can see Chrome 'working'.

So the problem was simply multiple tabs in Chrome aren't allowed to run concurrently.